# How to use preprocessor directives inside a MENU in MFC .rc file?

Tags: mfc

I want to be able to dynamically change code in my resource file depending on which version of my app is being ran. For example, I have an about menu. I would like the about menuitem to have a different description based on a preprocessor directive. The issue I have is I am able to add the code in. But when I edit the resource file and save it, the .aps file overwrites my preprocessor directives. How can I get around this? The code below is an example of what I would like to have in my resource script.

```
IDR_EXAMPLE_MENU MENU
BEGIN

/*


Other Menu items

*/

POPUP "&Help"
BEGIN
    MENUITEM "&Help Topics",                ID_HELP_FINDER
    MENUITEM SEPARATOR
#ifdef TEST_APP
    MENUITEM "&About TEST...",               ID_APP_ABOUT
#else
    MENUITEM "&About RELEASE...",             ID_APP_ABOUT
#endif
    END
END
```

If I am running the TEST version I would like it to display "About TEST" in the menuitem and if it the RELEASE version I would like it to display "About RELEASE" 
How can I add code like this to my resource file without having the .aps file overwrite the preprocessor directives when saving the .rc file?

Edit: [This explains how files are affected by resource editing.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/files-affected-by-resource-editing)

Comment: You could have two different commands `MENUITEM "&About TEST...",  ID_APP_ABOUTTEST` and `MENUITEM "&About RELEASE...",           ID_APP_ABOUTMENU` permanantly and delete one of them dynamically in the corresponding `OnUpdate` handlers. It's very simple. Let me know if this is an option and I'll write a more complete answer. That way you can completely avoid the usage of preprocessor commands which are problematic if you use the VS resource editor.

Comment: This could be one possible solution. Most of the code base uses preprocessors so I might do it that way just because that is how it is done everywhere else. I am curious to see a complete answer if you want to write one.

Comment: I just saw you've accepted A. A's solution. Please let me know if you're still interested in an answer as I suggested in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your code in separate rc files and include them using the [*Compile-Time Directives*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/mfc/tn035-using-multiple-resource-files-and-header-files-with-visual-cpp#compile-time-directives) field of the *Set includes* dialog. See [Using Multiple Resource Files in the Same Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/mfc/tn035-using-multiple-resource-files-and-header-files-with-visual-cpp)

If the resources are not changed frequently you can move them to the .rc2 file which is not modified by the Resource editor. And you can use pre-processor freely.

The other option is to create multiple .rc files (for example copy the original .rc file and remove the rest) and include them conditionally in the "Resource Includes.. > Compile-time directives" section which the Resource editors stores in the .rc file and repeats at the end of the .rc file as-is.

For example:

Create two .rc files like

ResourcesDebug.rc:

```
....

POPUP "&Help"
BEGIN
    MENUITEM "&Help Topics",                ID_HELP_FINDER
    MENUITEM SEPARATOR
    MENUITEM "&About TEST...",               ID_APP_ABOUT
    END
END

....
```

ResourcesRelease.rc:

```
....

POPUP "&Help"
BEGIN
    MENUITEM "&Help Topics",                ID_HELP_FINDER
    MENUITEM SEPARATOR
    MENUITEM "&About RELEASE...",             ID_APP_ABOUT
    END
END

....
```

You can add them to your repo, but need not to add them to the project. But if you add them to your project you have to exclude them from the compilation.

Compile-time directives (Resource view > Right click the .rc):

```
#define _AFX_NO_SPLITTER_RESOURCES
#define _AFX_NO_OLE_RESOURCES
#define _AFX_NO_TRACKER_RESOURCES
#define _AFX_NO_PROPERTY_RESOURCES

#include "res\TestApp.rc2"  // non-Microsoft Visual C++ edited resources

#ifdef TEST_APP
    #include ResourcesDebug.rc
#else
    #include ResourcesRelease.rc
#endif

....
```

Some more links:

- [Files Affected by Resource Editing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/files-affected-by-resource-editing)
- [How to: Include Resources at Compile Time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/how-to-include-resources-at-compile-time)

Comment: But let's say I have to make edits to that new resource file and when saved it overwrites it removing the preprocessor directives. It would be fine to put the preprocessor directives in the same .rc file if they weren't being overwritten when saved. Maybe I don't fully understand you solution. Can you elaborate?

Comment: This worked. I ended up putting everything that I didn't want to be changed into an .rc2 file.

Comment: It works but is not most easy to maintain. The whole Visual Studio Resource editor is just an antic piece of code. @xMRi solution sounds interesting but never tried it.

Answer (score 3):

It is also possible to have one resource like e menu twice inside your resource file.

Each resource can have a condition in its properties. And you can have a resource with the same name twice in your resources.

[image]

You may add the condition _DEBUG to the first resource. Just copy it and give the the condition _RELEASE. Rename it back to the same Id.

[image]

Comment: Looks good. Here is a post on the MSDN forums on haw it actual work - [Preprocessor directive for resource inclusion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/277177d0-0a25-4254-b58f-5aa454deecd3/preprocessor-directive-for-resource-inclusion?forum=vcgeneral)

Answer (score 1):

You want to be able to use the resource editor of VS, but it only knows how to generate 1 kind of .rc output, and that is WITHOUT any of your #define values.  You can't have it both ways.  You can use compiler directives and edit the .rc (or .rc2) file by hand, or accept the output of VS.

A possibility may be to let you edit the file in VS using the resource editor, and then write a post-processing program that kind of understands the general content of your .RC and re-generate the "desired" .RC replacing the raw content with your compiler directives.  It's do-able, but the trade-offs are very specific to your application.

Comment: An alternative is to have 2 different (but similar) menu resources, one called IDR_EXAMPLE_TEST_MENU, and one called IDR_EXAMPLE_RELEASE_MENU, then in your SOURCE code, use compiler directives to utilize IDR_EXAMPLE_TEST_MENU xor IDR_EXAMPLE_RELEASE_MENU